# char cannot be dereferenced error6

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a interface that user have to input their subject GPA and credit for relevant subject. then calculate it and show it on a text field. I have done that part. Then i want to send this GPA value to a text file and return that value with "your overall gpa is-(calculated GPA value)". i was trying to read that data from text file by characters. but i want to show it in a text field by pressing a button. character data type cannot display in a text field. I have tried to convert that array of characters to a string. but there is a error. I'm a beginner in java and sry for my grammar mistakes.error shown in this line-"str += c.toString();"

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("GPA.txt");
        try {
            // creates the file
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(cal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        writer = new FileWriter(file);
        // Writes the content to the file
        writer.write("Your Overall GPA is"+jTextField7.getText());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        //Creates a FileReader Object
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        char [] a = new char[50];

        String str = "";

        fr.read(a); // reads the content to the array
        for(char c : a)


        str += c.toString();// error shown in here


            jTextField8.setText(str);

        fr.close();        :
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(cal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(cal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char is primitive type and does not have method toString(), try this:

```
str += c;
```

You may also try this:

```
//String str = "";//<-- not required
fr.read(a); // reads the content to the array
jTextField8.setText(new String(a));//<-- no loop required
```